# ASP.NET Core Web API targeting .NET 8 on Azure App Service

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, .net-8.0

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API that I've been running on Azure App Service Windows platform. This app was targeting .NET 7 and today I updated it to target .NET 8. It compiles and runs fine locally.

According to this announcement, .NET 8 is now available on Azure App Service: https://azure.github.io/AppService/2023/11/14/dotnet8-ga.html

I deployed the app to Azure App Service and then changed the .NET version to .NET 8 -- see below:

[image]

This didn't work and I kept getting the following error:

> ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies

I then found this post on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/17v7qb5/http_error_50031_ancm_failed_to_find_native/

So, I went ahead and installed `ASP.NET Core .NET 8 x64` and `x86` through Kudu under Advanced Tools -- see below:

[image]

I then stopped and restarted the app on Azure App Service several times and it's still not working. When I try to hit an endpoint on my API, it spins and spins for a long time and comes back with "Service Unavailable" error but according to app dashboard on Azure, it's up and running.

Any suggestions? Anyone else is having upgrade to .NET 8 issues?

PS: the deployment of my API app is done through GitHub actions and I did update the .NET version to .NET 8 -- see below:

[image]

Comment: After checking the issue, and found the .net 8 not available in all regions. Menintherigging's finding is useful. For more details, you also could [check this thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1429937/when-will-net-core-8-web-apps-run-on-azure).

Answer (score 3):

I have created a basic **ASP .NET Core Web API** with version **.NET-8.0** and deployed to Azure App Service using GitHub actions.

**Steps Followed:**

- Created an ASP .NET Core Web API project with .NET 8 version and able to run locally.
- Modified **program.cs**:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(x =>
{

    x.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Web API V1");

#if DEBUG
    x.RoutePrefix = "swagger"; // For localhost
#else
    x.RoutePrefix = string.Empty; //  For azure
#endif
}
);
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

- Pushed the application to GitHub.
- Created a **Windows Azure App Service** with **.NET-8.0(Early Access)** as run time stack.

[image]

- Deploying the application to Azure using GitHub Actions.

**My Workflow:**

Below is the workflow I have used to deploy the application.

```yaml
name: Build and deploy ASP.Net Core app to Azure Web App - <web_app_name>

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: '8.x'
          include-prerelease: true

      - name: Build with dotnet
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release

      - name: dotnet publish
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: .net-app
          path: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: .net-app
      
      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: '<web_app_name>'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: .
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_FXXXXXXXXXX }}
```

**Deployment Status:**

[image]

Running the application successfully.

[image]

If the issue still persists while deploying the application, add `--self-contained` in dotnet's publish command in the GitHub workflow.

```
      - name: dotnet publish
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp --self-contained true
```

Answer (score 2):

I have basically the same problem deploying to Azure with .NET Core 8 web app. You can use the 'self-contained' as a workaround.
However, I discovered that if you deploy to 'East US' it works fine, but 'UK South' produces 'Service Unavailable'.

Comment: I received this info: "Because now. .NET 8 is still in the Early Access phase, and some regions should be in beta, and when there are no problems when it is stable, it will be deployed in every regions.

So please be patient and wait for the App Service Team update."

Comment: UK south has now been updated for me

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has now [released a fix for this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Net-8-runtime-is-not-installed-in-a-NE/10520839#TPIN-N10533340).

I have tested in the Australia Southeast region (which wasn't working) and it now works.

Comment: I clicked the link to view the solution but there is no solution listed.  I did all the same things mentioned in the issue and still I am at version 7.x.  What is the solution?

Comment: Interesting - as soon as the Microsoft comment appeared saying they had fixed the issue, .net 8 projects started working on Azure App Service for me without needing to do anything else. I don't know why it wouldn't be working for others.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too, and for me the solution was caused by a .Net 7 site extension that had to be updated using Advanced Tools -> Site Extensions. After updating the extension (ASP.Net Core Logging Integration) to the .Net 8 version and restarting the app service, everything was fine.

Note that I am simply using click-to-publish deployment from within VS 2022 and are publishing to Western Europe region.