# HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start using azure webservice

Tags: .net, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

I deployed .net 7 api on azure web service ,after deployment when i tried to access my site it shows this HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start

i triedto diagonose but i failed !

i used to azure cloud platform to deploy my apis but it doest work

Comment: Could please tell how did you deploy to azure web app service

Comment: @Yawar manzoor sheikh if you are using [default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-api-management-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-7.0) code [change](https://i.imgur.com/DfW9spc.png) the program class and [publish](https://i.imgur.com/wSY2ihb.png) the code to [Azure](https://i.imgur.com/okmlDuN.png)

Comment: please share the code you tried

Comment: Are you using the default code? Provide the code that you tried. Where could you see the error "HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start" in the browser?

Comment: @sampath using github actions

Comment: As per the SO Guidelines, the Code should be shared. can you please try to post in text format for the forum understanding/benefit?

Comment: @Yawarmanzoorsheikh - Please share your code so that it will be easy to help you out.Does your App has any DB configurations or a simple web app?

Comment: please follow the Yml reference from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77483755/asp-net-core-web-api-targeting-net-8-on-azure-app-service)

Answer (score 0):

I created an **ASP .NET Web API** and deployed it to Azure App Service using GitHub actions.

**I followed these steps:**

- Create an ASP .NET Web API project and make changes in **program.cs** and run  locally.
- The below code is a sample ASP NET  to set up a web application with Swagger for API documentation.

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(x =>
{

    x.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Web API V1");

#if DEBUG
    x.RoutePrefix = "swagger"; 
#else
    x.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
#endif
}
);
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

- Pushed the Code to Git .

[image]

**Git action states:**
[image]

**Azure:**
[image]